# Picking up Environment Variables in Cypress with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, environment-variables, cypress

I'm working to add tests to a pre-existing monorepo that uses TypeScript in the main. All other tests are in TypeScript and for mine, I wish to use Cypress.

I need to run them on two separate environments and need to understand why my environment variables are not being picked up.

It's probably something very obvious but I am a TS and JS newcomer so hoping for some gentle guidance.

Directly under `/config` I have `dev.json` and `prod.json` for the two envs:

```
{
  "env": {
    "ENV": "dev",
    "BASE_URL": "http://example.com",

  }
}
```

My `plugins/index.ts` as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');

export default (on: Cypress.PluginEvents, _config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions): void => {
    on('task', {
        log(message) {
            console.log(message)

            return null
        }
    });

    on('task', {
        table(message) {
            console.table(message);
            return null;
        },
    });

    /**
     * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
     */
    function getConfigurationByFile(file) {
        const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve('config', `${file}.json`
        );

        return fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile);
    }

    /**
     * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
     */
    module.exports = (on, config) => {
        const file = config.env.configFile || 'dev';

        return getConfigurationByFile(file);
    };

}
```

Example of use within a test spec:

```js
beforeEach(()=> {
  cy.login(Cypress.env('BASE_URL'), 
})
```

Example script in `package.json`

```
"test:headless": "npm cypress run --env 'configFile=%ENV%",
```

Running from CLI as: `ENV=dev npm run test:headless`

This fails to pick up the url from the `dev.json`

Again, I'm sure it's something dumb but some pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `%ENV%.json`, instead of just `%ENV%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `CYPRESS_` prefix [Option #3: CYPRESS_*](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-2-cypress-env-json)

> Any OS-level environment variable on your machine that starts with either CYPRESS_ or cypress_ will automatically be added to Cypress' environment variables and made available to you.

```js
CYPRESS_configFile=dev npm run test:headless

...

const file = config.env.configFile || 'dev';
```